# Upgrading to Jetpack Compose bill of materials 2023.08.00 requires me to change targetSdk to 34

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**I'm using compose bill of materials to manage my compose versions in the project.
I updated the bom version to 2023:08:00 and now I'm getting this error:**

```
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 8.1.0 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdk of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).
```

How can I update my compose version without changing the compileSdk and targetSdk to 34?

**Project level gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = '8.1.0'
        kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
        ksp_version = '1.9.0-1.0.13'
        compose_bom_version = '2023.08.00'
        compose_compiler_version = '1.5.1'
        accompanist_version = '0.31.6-rc'
        hilt_version = '2.44.1'
        hilt_navigation_compose_version = '1.0.0'
        room_version = '2.5.2'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "${kotlin_version}" apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "${hilt_version}" apply false
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "${ksp_version}" apply false
}
```

**App level gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    namespace ''
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler_version
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0"

    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:$hilt_navigation_compose_version"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // Jetpack Compose
    implementation platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:$compose_bom_version")
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest"

    // Accompanist
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:$accompanist_version"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:$accompanist_version"

    // Splash
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1"

    // Test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:$compose_bom_version")
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"
}
```

I tried to update jetpack compose bill of material version to the latest one without having to target android 14.

Comment: I know I can change only the compileSdk to 34 but I don't want to change that either

Comment: Why do you fear changing the `compileSdk` version?

Comment: it may introduce unexpected changes @CommonsWare

Comment: You might get some new and exciting Lint warnings. That is about it.

Comment: More than a lint warning, AGP 8.1 says it doesn't support compileSdk=34, but AGP 8.2 isn't released yet.  It seems that the Compose team makes their release before the AGP team, and doesn't recognize that not everyone is using a pre-release AGP.  : /

Comment: (as documented: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#api-level-support, AGP 8.1 and Android Studio 2022.3.1 don't support compileSdk=34, and those are currently the most recent stable releases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same situation, and what I do is just changing the compileSdk and buildToolsVersion version to 34(and 34.0.0). That doesn't require you to change  the targetSdk version.

Answer (score 4):

[Android 14 reached stability on 3 June](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/overview#platform_stability), so there is no real reason to avoid it any longer. The sources are also now [published](https://androiddev.social/@ianlake/110862157065161400). The upgrade to targetSdk34 also works with AGP 8.0. So you can easily comply with the requirement. There is no other way if you want to use the latest BOM. Source: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C04TPPEQKEJ/p1691617447309779